# M2crypto compilation on aix

Tags: python, swig, aix, m2crypto

When compiling M2Crypto module on AIX5.1 with following scrambled command:

`/opt/local/python/2.7.3/bin/python setup.py build_ext --swig /opt/local/swig/1.3.4/bin/swig -I /opt/local/swig/1.3.4/share/swig/1.3.40/:/opt/local/swig/1.3.4/share/swig/1.3.40/python --openssl /opt/local/openssl/0.9.8/ --library-dirs=/opt/local/openssl/0.9.8/lib/`

Output comes as:

`/opt/local/swig/1.3.4/share/swig/1.3.40//exception.i:11: Error: CPP #error ""This version of exception.i should not be used"". Use the -cpperraswarn option to continue swig processing.`

List of available compilers:

- --compiler=bcpp     Borland C++ Compiler
- --compiler=cygwin   Cygwin port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
- --compiler=emx      EMX port of GNU C Compiler for OS/2
- --compiler=mingw32  Mingw32 port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
- --compiler=msvc     Microsoft Visual C++
- --compiler=unix     standard UNIX-style compiler

Passing anything of these doesn't seem to work either. While in /opt/local/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile I see:

`CC=             xlc_r`
`CXX=            g++`

That should be working with xlc_r compiler in first place.
Passing -cpperraswarn to that as suggestion returns:
`error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'posix' with 'pperraswarn' compiler`

There should be way how to make it compile with different compiler than there is defined in available compiler list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in essence,

Swig shall be compiles in a bit different way,

```
./configure --with-python=/opt/local/python/2.7.3/bin/python --prefix=/opt/local/swig/1.3.40 CC=xlc_r CXX=/usr/vacpp/bin/xlC_r
```

Correct compiler options were important in this case.

For M2Crypto then:

`/opt/local/python/2.7.3/bin/python setup.py build_ext --openssl=/opt/local/openssl/1.0.0a/`

after that issue usual build and install.
Hope this stuff will be useful for someone in future.